# C++ Linker complains multiple definition of char* but not std::string

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, linker-errors, linkage

In a big project, I have a .h file which defines a lot of constants within a namespace. Introducing const char*   constants results in linker errors complaining of multiple definitions.

**ex.h**

```
#include <string>
namespace Dv
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    const std::string NAME = "bobo";

    const char* NAME2 = "fred";  // <-- ERROR: multiple definition of `Dv::NAME2'
}
```

**exA.cpp**

```
#include "ex.h"
void aFunction() { printf("this is aFunction\n"); }
```

**exB.cpp**

```
#include "ex.h"    
void aFunction(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    aFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile and Link**

```
g++ -c exA.cpp
g++ -c exB.cpp
g++ exA.o exB.o -o ex
exB.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `Dv::NAME2'
exA.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker error happens if NAME2 is included in the .h file.  Why?

If MAX is also a POD (like char[]?), why does the linker not complain of multiple *int MAX* definitions?  (or multiple *std::string NAME* definitions for that matter?)

I don't understand what's special about char[] in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: `const char *` is not constant. It is a (modifiable) pointer to some constant chars. You can for example do `Dv::NAME2 = "something else"` to make it point to something else. You want `const char * const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (3.5 Program and linkage)

> 3 A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
>   the name of
>
> **— a non-volatile variable that is explicitly declared const or constexpr and neither explicitly declared extern nor previously
>   declared to have external linkage; or**

and

> 4 An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly
>   within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. **All other
>   namespaces have external linkage.** A name having namespace scope that
>   has not been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the
>   enclosing namespace if it is the name of — a variable; or

In this namespace definition

```
namespace Dv
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    const std::string NAME = "bobo";

    const char* NAME2 = "fred";  // <-- ERROR: multiple definition of `Dv::NAME2'
}
```

(the only) variable `NAME2` is not a constant and hence has external linkage.

You could make it as having internal linkage defining it for example with keyword static. For example

```
namespace Dv
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    const std::string NAME = "bobo";

    static const char* NAME2 = "fred";
}
```

Or could define it as a constant

```
namespace Dv
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    const std::string NAME = "bobo";

    const char * const NAME2 = "fred";
}
```

Comment: Maybe better is to make it const: `const char* const NAME2 = "fred";` ?

Comment: Does the standard actually say it's an error to have multiple definitions, though? All I could find is that ODR requires exactly one definition of each variable or function that is odr-used, which would disallow multiple definitions in general, but does not cover the OP's code, where none of the three end up used.

Comment: @hvd  This is a linker error. The compiler simply marked this variable as having external linkage.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I understand what the compiler is doing and what the linker is doing, but I don't understand how the standard allows that behaviour. (I certainly understand that it *should* allow that behaviour, FWIW.)

Comment: @hvd  ODR usage means that in fact the compiler is allowed not to define an object if for example its address or a reference to it is not used.. In this way you may not define static constant class members.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, I understand that. If an object or function is not odr-used, the rule that it must have exactly one definition does not and should not apply. So, again, if that rule does not apply, what rule prohibits multiple definitions of objects or functions that are not odr-used? Or was the point of your earlier comment that you feel the behaviour of the linker is not meant to be covered by the C++ standard? (If so, I disagree.)

Comment: @hvd  It seems that it is dependent on the linker options.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You keep posting comments that completely miss the point of mine. Forget it. I'll ask a question of my own. But for the benefit of others, if someone else posts a comment on your answer, please try to understand that comment before responding. If you're unable to (possibly because the comment is unintelligible), do request clarification, but responses that miss the point (something I have been guilty of myself) are a waste of everyone's time, including your own.